# HTML Javascript - How to add function to an input statement and hide the input statement unless Yes is checked, then unhide

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn and understand javascript. I am new to javascript.

I was able to figure out how to hide and unhide radio buttons depending on what is checked.

I would like to do the same for the input tag - I was unsuccessful.

Once the user click on Yes - the input tag appears with saying "30 days from today is & the calculate the date by adding 30 days to current date" - via calling another function.

I was able to create a function that adds 30 days to today's date - thanks to a senior member from this site.

Unfortunately I am not able to put it together.

HTML:

```
   <div id="divDeathOccurred" class="fieldRow">
   <div class="leftLabel labelWidth22">
     <label for="">A. Has a death occurred?</label>
   </div>
   <div class="leftField">
   <div class="formField34">
     <input id="rbDeathOccurred" name="rbDeathOccurred" type="radio" 
      class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Death Occurred" title="Death Occurred" 
      value="Yes" onclick="javascript:USAYesNoCheckDO();" />Yes
     <input id="rbDeathOccurred" name="rbDeathOccurred" type="radio" 
      class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Death Occurred" title="Death Occurred" 
      value="No" onclick="javascript:USAYesNoCheckDO();" />No
    </div>
     </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="USADOYesNo" style="display:none">
    <ol type="a">
      <li>Is there a reasonable possibility that a device failure or 
         malfunction was a direct or indirect factor in the death? 
     <br>
      <input id="rbDOYesNo" name="rbDOYesNo" type="radio"  
       class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Yes - Reportable" title="Yes - 
       Reportable" value="Yes" 
        onclick="javascript:USDeviceFailure30Days();"/>Yes - Reportable    
       <input id="rbDOYesNo" name="rbDOYesNo" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" alt="No - Follow tree below" title="No -  
        Follow tree below" value="No" 
        onclick="javascript:USDeviceFailure30Days();"/>No
      <br>
     <input id="date30Days" type="text" onclick="javascript:date30Days();"/>
     </li>
    </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
```

1st Function yesnoCheck.js:

```
function USAYesNoCheckDO() {

  if (document.getElementById('rbDeathOccurred').checked) {        
     document.getElementById('USADOYesNo').style.display = 'block';        
     } else  document.getElementById('USADOYesNo').style.display = 'none';  
    }

 function USDeviceFailure30Days() {
   if (document.getElementById('rbDOYesNo').checked) {        
    document.getElementById('date30Days').style.display = 'block';        
   } else  document.getElementById('date30Days').style.display = 'none';
   }
```

2nd function date30.js:

```
 function date30Days(){
   var dt = new Date();
   dt.setDate( dt.getDate() + 30 );
   var mo = dt.getMonth() + 1; // JS months are 0 to 11, so need to add 1
   var dy = dt.getDate();
   var yr = dt.getYear() % 100; // just to make sure only 2 digit year
   var dueDate = (mo < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + mo + "/" + ( dy < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + 
    dy + "/" + (yr < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + yr;
    var text = "30 days from today is "

    text + dueDate; <--- this is where I want to print underneath the 
    Yes/no, once the user click on Yes - 30 days from today is mm/dd/yyyy.
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

IreneS

By the way - sorry for the words of death, I work in a pharmaceutical company.

Comment: Do you want the value to show up inside the input field or below?

Comment: Once the user check yes, I need the value to show up underneath the Yes/No.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the value of the `<input>` field like this:

```
document.getElementById('date30Days').value = text + dueDate; ;
```

But if you want the text to be above the `<input>` field then add a new `<div>` above it and then modify the contents of that `<div>`. For this, i added the following `<div>` above the `<input>`:

```
<div id="reminder"></div>
```

Then modify the `.innerHTML` property of the `<div>` like this:

```
document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML = text + dueDate;
```

To do this on the click of the radio button just call `date30Days()` within the `if` statement of `USDeviceFailure30Days()` but then you also need to reset the value to `''` in the `else` like this:

```
 function USDeviceFailure30Days() {
   if (document.getElementById('rbDOYesNo').checked) {        
    document.getElementById('date30Days').style.display = 'block';        
     date30Days();
   } else {
     document.getElementById('date30Days').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML = '';
     }
   }
```

Then remove the from `onclick="javascript:date30Days();"` from the `<input>`

```
 <input id="date30Days" type="text" />
```

---

Here is a modified version of your code:

```js
function USAYesNoCheckDO() {
  if (document.getElementById('rbDeathOccurred').checked) {        
     document.getElementById('USADOYesNo').style.display = 'block';        
     } else  document.getElementById('USADOYesNo').style.display = 'none';  
    }

 function USDeviceFailure30Days() {
   if (document.getElementById('rbDOYesNo').checked) {        
    document.getElementById('date30Days').style.display = 'block';        
     date30Days();
   } else {
     document.getElementById('date30Days').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML = '';
     }
   }

 function date30Days(){
   var dt = new Date();
   dt.setDate( dt.getDate() + 30 );
   var mo = dt.getMonth() + 1; // JS months are 0 to 11, so need to add 1
   var dy = dt.getDate();
   var yr = dt.getYear() % 100; // just to make sure only 2 digit year
   var dueDate = (mo < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + mo + "/" + ( dy < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + 
    dy + "/" + (yr < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + yr;
    var text = "30 days from today is "

    document.getElementById('reminder').innerHTML = text + dueDate; ;        
    }
```

```html
<div id="divDeathOccurred" class="fieldRow">
   <div class="leftLabel labelWidth22">
     <label for="">A. Has a death occurred?</label>
   </div>
   <div class="leftField">
   <div class="formField34">
     <input id="rbDeathOccurred" name="rbDeathOccurred" type="radio" 
      class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Death Occurred" title="Death Occurred" 
      value="Yes" onclick="javascript:USAYesNoCheckDO();" />Yes
     <input id="rbDeathOccurred" name="rbDeathOccurred" type="radio" 
      class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Death Occurred" title="Death Occurred" 
      value="No" onclick="javascript:USAYesNoCheckDO();" />No
    </div>
     </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="USADOYesNo" style="display:none">
    <ol type="a">
      <li>Is there a reasonable possibility that a device failure or 
         malfunction was a direct or indirect factor in the death? 
     <br>
      <input id="rbDOYesNo" name="rbDOYesNo" type="radio"  
       class="radiobuttonfield" alt="Yes - Reportable" title="Yes - 
       Reportable" value="Yes" 
        onclick="javascript:USDeviceFailure30Days();"/>Yes - Reportable    
       <input id="rbDOYesNo" name="rbDOYesNo" type="radio"
        class="radiobuttonfield" alt="No - Follow tree below" title="No -  
        Follow tree below" value="No" 
        onclick="javascript:USDeviceFailure30Days();"/>No
      <br><div id="reminder"></div>
     <input id="date30Days" type="text" />
     </li>
    </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
```

---

Comment: Tim Penner - when i try to run the code through this website it works.

Comment: but when I added your recommendation to my code and run it - it does not work.  I am not sure why.  I checked and checked to see if I implemented your fix correctly, which I did but still doesn't work.  Not sure why.  Do you have suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Tim - I don't know what I did but now it works as you have coded.  So this part work now - the only thing, is it possible to have the value appears once the yes is clicked and no need to click in the input box for the value to appear?  I do not have to use the input tag, whichever tag works better.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @IreneS i modified my answer a bit more to get the result you described in your last comment. Your code could probably be cleaned up a lot, but that wasn't my intention. I only intended to answer the question.

Comment: Tim - thank you so much - I know my codes need to be cleaned a lot - this is my first ever javascript experience - I have  a long way to learn and get my codes to be more professional.  It works great but the only thing now that for some reason it used to work but now it doesn't - if for the user click on yes - the date comes up and if the user decide to click on No - the due date text hides but for whatever reason the user decide on clicking yes again - the text does not show.  Any ideas?  Thank you again?

Comment: Tim - I figured it out - I have put the input statement within the div - so that is why it wasn't working - once I took the input statement outside the div - it worked - Yeh! - Thank you again